# How to restore origin from local repository

Tags: git

One of the best in git, that it is distributed. Let's say, we working on a project, all the latest branches are pulled and merged to my local repository.

Then a server crash happens, and there was no backup, no mirroring, etc.. So the central repository has lost.

Is it possible to restore the central repository with all the branches, from my local repository?

Something like `git init --bare --shared=group ./repo.git` on server, and then `git please --recover --with=allbraches mylocal.repository to ssh://...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your local repo, `git push origin --all`. I am assuming that the new repo on the restored server has the same URL. If the URL has changed, then do `git remote set-url origin <new URL>` first.

Comment: but this will only push all your checkout branches. if you did not checkout locally all the branches they will not be pushed. If you need them i have posted you a tiny script which will check them out for you and than you can push them.

Comment: @CodeWizard yes, that is another assumption which I did not state.

Answer (score 2):

Do these commands

```
# Check remote Git server.
git remote -v

# If Git server changed or doesn't exist.
git remote set-url origin your_remote_git_server

# For example.
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/donhuvy/elasticsearch.git

# Check your permission on Git server. You must be master user.
# Force push all branches to remote Git server.
git push origin --all --force

# Force push all tags to remote Git server.
git push origin --tags --force

# Check result after the above steps by few command.
git status
git branch --all
git log --oneline -10
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. @Code-Apprentice answered first, and his solution has worked. I really do not get why is you answer has downvoted.  It seems legit, commented well.

Answer (score 1):

Since your remote was removed you don't have any origin yet so you will have to create a new repo on the server and than update your remote url to point to the new one

If you dont want the local branches simply push the ones you need.

Here is a scrip which im using to checkout all branches and than push them to the new remote

```
#!/bin/bash

# update the new origin 
# (or leave the same one if its the same as the original)

git remote set-url origin <new-url> 
# loop over all the original branches
# 1. check them out as local branches 
# 2. set the origin as the track branch
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
    git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
done

# now push all branches and tags
git push origin --all    
git push origin --tags
```

---

#### What does the script do?

**`git branch -a`**
get a list of all the local branches

**`| grep remotes`**
The branch names are : 'remotes/origin/' so this will remove the remotes from the branch names

**`| grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`**
remove the master (current branch) and [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716) which is an alias to the latest commit

Comment: Thank you for you effort, I am surprised why Do Nhu Vys and your answer has downvoted.

Comment: I have no idea why. its a working and excellent solution. Fell free to vote for them if you think they are good answers.

Comment: This is certainly more thorough than my own answer. Of course, this will push branches which have been fetched but not checked out. For any branches not fetched, the OP is SOL.